# Should I use “at” or “in”? “... carried out at/in the university”

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> The research is not being carried out **at** the university

or

> The research is not being carried out **in** the university.

I don't understand the difference between them. Could someone please help me with it?

Comment: Hi, could you show what you **did** to "understand the difference between them"?

Answer (score -1):

In the specific context (insofar as I can identify it) of your examples, there is little if any difference. Both would to be interpreted as referring to a particular university. And both assume the listener knows *which* particular university. And, again in this context, both would be taken as referring to that university as a whole, as opposed to a particular geographical point within. For my part, as a native speaker, I would tend to use the first, not the second, but that would be more style than substance.

However, freed from your specific context, there can be a difference. As above, both “in the university” and “at the university” would still tend to be interpreted as referring to a mutually-known particular university. But there can be a difference between the two in that “in” would often tend to be interpreted as meaning inside a building at the university, whereas “at” is more vague and could refer to anywhere in the university campus as a whole.

And for completeness, I’ll note that removing the article, “the”, changes things further. In contrast with the original versions, which refer to a specific university, both “in university” and “at university” might be interpreted as referring to **universities** as a whole, or to the abstract idea of a university. As a result, when “the” is omitted, the building versus campus distinction doesn’t exist between “in” an “at”.

Examples:

> Darn it, I think I left my wallet **in the university**. It’s either in chemistry lecture room B7, or in the cafeteria.

> Instead of the movie theater, let’s meet **at the university** this week. How about outside the cafeteria, at 7pm?

> I studied English **at university**, but quite honestly I think I’ve learned just as much about the language using *ell.stackexchange.com.*

> When addressing a teacher, it is common, **in university** circles at least, to first bow or curtsy and then jump up on a table and cry out, *“O Captain, my Captain!”*

Comment: As a speaker of AmE, I can think of no situation where I would ever say *...in the university...*  I am not even sure how to understand it.  I might say it as a part of a larger prepositional phrase such as *...in the university system...* but that means *in the system* not *in the university*.  I would never say I left something **in** the university and **in university circles** means *in circles* not *in university*.